# Mocking parameterized asynchronous method

Tags: c#, mocking

```
    var controller = new Mock<JobOfferController>(context);
controller.Setup(m => m.UploadCvToAzureStorage(It.IsAny<IFormFile>()))
.Returns(Task.FromResult("cv-url"));
```

This part of code returns following error:"System.NotSupportedException : Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member member: m => m.UploadCvToAzureStorage(It.IsAny())". Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moq will not mock a concrete class's non-virutal members because it can't override the code that runs to implement your setup. You need to either mock the interface that the class implements.

If you have this:

```
public interface IJobOfferController
{
    Task<string> UploadCvToAzureStorage(IFormFile file);
}

public class JobOfferController : IJobOfferController
{
    public Task<string> UploadCvToAzureStorage(IFormFile file) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Then you're set up would be:

```
public void SetUp()
{
    //this is trying to mock the concrete class and will fail
    var controller = new Mock<JobOfferController>(context);            
    controller.Setup(m => m.UploadCvToAzureStorage(It.IsAny<IFormFile>()))
        .Returns(Task.FromResult("cv-url"));


    //This Mocks the interface and sets up a return value for that interface
    var mockController = new Mock<IJobOfferController>();
    mockController.Setup(m => m.UploadCvToAzureStorage(It.IsAny<IFormFile>()))
        .Returns(Task.FromResult("cv-url"));
}
```

Additionally, when your mocking async methods you can drop the `.FromResult` and just use `ReturnsAsync`

```
controller.Setup(m => m.UploadCvToAzureStorage(It.IsAny<IFormFile>()))
    .ReturnsAsync("cv-url");
```

**Or**

If your controller does not have an interface the other option is to make your controller's method virtual so that Moq can override it with your setup:

```
public class JobOfferController : IJobOfferController
{
    public virtual Task<string> UploadCvToAzureStorage(IFormFile file) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}

//now the setup works
var controller = new Mock<JobOfferController>(context);            
controller.Setup(m => m.UploadCvToAzureStorage(It.IsAny<IFormFile>()))
    .ReturnsAsync("cv-url");
```